# SqlPartialTypes not working after update nuget package

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've got an ASP.NET MVC5 Project with EF6.

After doing an update to all nuget package including Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (ver 14.0.314.76), all the query related to spartial type not working any more, and it telling me to include this line of code inside my Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

But it doesn't fix the problems

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.
```

Here is what I've tried so far

- Reinstall nuget package
- Set the .dll in SqlServerTypes Folder to copy alsway, delete bin and obj folder and rebuild

To test if it working, insert this simple code to your Index method in HomeController

```
DbGeometry test = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(297937 574201)", 27700);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Entity Framework. The dependency on SQL Server Types is set to version 10 or 11, rather than version 10 or higher.

The workaround is to add a redirect to use version 14 when version 10 is requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Entity Framework bug report: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/244